# Can GRE scores be sent to different universities at different times?

Tags: phd, gre

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I could not find reference to it either on this site or on the GRE/ETS website.

I am a UK maths undergrad currently applying for a PhD in pure mathematics. I am going to apply to UC Berkeley in the States and my application - along with my GRE scores - is nearly ready to send. I want to get it sent off soon so that I have time to research and work on my other applications, both for UK universities and potentially another US university.

However, I haven't decided which other US institution to apply to yet so I was thinking of sending Berkeley my application along with my GRE scores and then sending them again later to whichever other place I decide on.

However the GRE website doesn't make it clear whether you can send scores on different occasions to different schools or if everything needs to be sent off at the same time. Do I need to decide on all my American institutions before I send the scores, or can I do it one university at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send additional score reports later, but you'll have to pay extra for those additional reports.